# Create a vector as a function call parameter

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, program-entry-point

I have no idea what i have to do in this situation..

```
Class Build_Using_Vector : public Another
{
 private:
         int Thing;
         vector<int> List_Elem;
 public:
         Build_Using_Vector(int TThing, vector<int> LList_Elem);
};
```

ok this is not a prob... the second part still is not a prob:

```
Build_Using_Vector::Build_Using_Vector(int TThing, vector<int> LList_Elem) : Another() 
 {
    Thing = TThing;
    List_Elem = LList_Elem;
 }
```

As i said this is not a prob.

The prob is there, in "main".
In my case is not "main" is another class... but i think is the same...

```
int main()
 {
   Build_Using_Vector Foo(5, ???) // i don't know how to build with a multiple of element for example 5,6,7)
   return 0;
 }
```

thank you

Comment: you could use a [initializer_list](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) if your C++ is fresh enough or create a temporary vector ad hoc which transports the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [list initilization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).  `Build_Using_Vector Foo(5, ???)` would be

```
Build_Using_Vector Foo(5, {5,6,7})
```

I would also suggest you use all member initialization with your constructor and change

```
Build_Using_Vector::Build_Using_Vector(int TThing, vector<int> LList_Elem) : Another() 
{
    Thing = TThing;
    List_Elem = LList_Elem;
}
```

To

```
Build_Using_Vector::Build_Using_Vector(int TThing, vector<int> LList_Elem) : Another() , Thing(TThing), List_Elem(LList_Elem) {}
```

Comment: Minor nitpick, but I would also advise the user to get rid of their horrible naming convention for parameters and just do `...Thing(Thing), List_Elem(List_Elem)...`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a C++11 conforming compiler then you will have to build the `std::vector` manually.

```
int main ()
{
    const int arr [] = {5, 6, 7} ;
    const unsigned arrSize = sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr [0]) ;

    std::vector <int> v1 (arr, arr + arrSize) ;
    Build_Using_Vector Foo(5, v1) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Or

```
int main ()
{    
    std::vector <int> v1 ;
    v1.push_back (5) ;
    v1.push_back (6) ;
    v1.push_back (7) ;        

    Build_Using_Vector Foo(5, v1) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Or

```
int main ()
{    
    Build_Using_Vector Foo(5, CallSomeFunctionThatReturnsAnStdVector()) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: yeah i thought about this solution but is impossible cause the rest of algorithm ;/

Comment: You could also use `Build_Using_Vector Foo(5, std::vector<int>(arr, arr + arrSize));`